# How to Include PNG Icons in Footnotes in R Markdown PDF Output?

Tags: r, png, kable, footnotes

I am trying to include small icons (saved as .png files) in the footnotes of my R Markdown document, which will be converted to a PDF file. I want these icons to provide additional visual information within the footnotes, but I am encountering difficulties achieving this.

I have attempted to use the  HTML tag and LaTeX's \includegraphics package, but the icons are not displaying correctly in the PDF output. Can anyone provide guidance on how to successfully include these icons in the footnotes of a PDF generated from R Markdown?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

```
# Load the required libraries
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

# Create example data 
data <- data.frame(
  Category = c("Toyota", "Honda", "Ford", "Nissan"),
  Count = c(50, 60, 45, 55),
  Minimum = c(100, 110, 95, 105),
  Maximum = c(200, 210, 195, 205)
)

# Define a vector with image links and descriptions in a footnote
footnote_text <- c(
  "Decreasing < -5% ![Arrow](Images/arrow_down.png)",
  "Slightly Decreasing -5 to -1% ![Arrow](Images/arrow_right_down.png)",
  "Stagnant -1 to +1% ![Arrow](Images/arrow_right.png)",
  "Slightly Increasing +1 to +5% ![Arrow](Images/arrow_right_up.png)",
  "Increasing > +5% ![Arrow](Images/arrow_up.png)"
)

# Create the table with adjusted column names
table <- kbl(data, booktabs = TRUE, col.names = c("Category", "Count", "Min", "Max")) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped"), font_size = 10, position = "center") %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "(n)" = 1, "in Dollars" = 2)) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Count" = 1, "Values" = 2))%>%
  add_footnote(footnote_text, notation="none")

# Display the table
table
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job. Provided your images stored in `Images` folder.

Basically you have to pass png images as `<img>` attribute. Then display the strings as html, meaning `add_footnote(..., escape = F)`.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(glue)

# Create example data 
data <- data.frame(
  Category = c("Toyota", "Honda", "Ford", "Nissan"),
  Count = c(50, 60, 45, 55),
  Minimum = c(100, 110, 95, 105),
  Maximum = c(200, 210, 195, 205)
)

footnote_text <- c(
  "Decreasing < -5%)",
  "Slightly Decreasing -5 to -1%",
  "Stagnant -1 to +1%",
  "Slightly Increasing +1 to +5%",
  "Increasing > +5%"
)
footnote_png_paths <- c(
  "Images/arrow_down.png",
  "Images/arrow_right_down.png",
  "Images/arrow_right.png",
  "Images/arrow_right_up.png",
  "Images/arrow_up.png"
)

display_annotation <- function(width = "20px", height = "20px") {
  glue_collapse(sapply(1:length(footnote_text), function(x) glue('{footnote_text[x]} <img src="{footnote_png_paths[x]}" alt="" width="{width}" height="{height}">')), '<br>')
  
}

# Create the table with adjusted column names
table <- kbl(data, booktabs = TRUE, col.names = c("Category", "Count", "Min", "Max")) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped"), font_size = 10, position = "center") %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "(n)" = 1, "in Dollars" = 2)) %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Count" = 1, "Values" = 2))%>%
  add_footnote(display_annotation(), notation = "symbol", escape = F)

# Display the table
table
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful input. Your proposed solution is giving me the following error when I try to knit it to a PDF.
! File ended while scanning use of \multicolumn. 
<inserted text> 
\par 
<*> test.tex 
Fehler: LaTeX failed to compile test.tex